# Sharing RDDs with storage level NONE among Spark jobs

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I have multiple Spark jobs which share a part of the dataflow graph including an expensive shuffle operation. If I persist that RDD, I see huge improvement (22x) as expected.

However, even when I keep the storage level of those RDDs as `NONE`, I still see upto 4x improvement just by sharing the RDDs among jobs.

Why?
I am under the assumption that Sark always recompute RDDs with storage level NONE and those are not subject to eviction/spilling.

My Spark version is 3.3.1. Showing the code is difficult as the code is spread in multiple files in a bigger system. I am essentially doing the following:

- Identify the repetitive (and expensive) Spark operation across jobs. I do that by maintaining my own lineage traces [1].
- After the first execution of those Spark operations, I keep the RDD handles locally in a cache, which is a hashmap <lineage-trace, RDD>.
- The next time onwards, when I get the same operation, I simply reuse the cached RDD.

If I persist the RDDs in the second step (by calling `rdd.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)`, I see a huge improvement. But even if I just reuse the same RDD (storage level `NONE`), I still see improvement.

[1] LIMA: Fine-grained Lineage Tracing and Reuse in Machine Learning Systems. Arnab Phani, Benjamin Rath, Matthias Boehm. SIGMOD 2021

Comment: That's a super interesting question! Can you share (by editing your question) what your Spark version is and how you exactly persist your RDDs (showing the code)?

Comment: I edited the question by adding more details about the version and what I am doing. Hope this helps @Koedlt.

Answer (score 1):

If we have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/fbbcf9434ac070dd4ced4fb9efe32899c6db12a9/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L180-L194) for the `rdd.persist(StorageLevel)` method, we see the following:

```
  def persist(newLevel: StorageLevel): this.type = {
    if (isLocallyCheckpointed) {
      // This means the user previously called localCheckpoint(), which should have already
      // marked this RDD for persisting. Here we should override the old storage level with
      // one that is explicitly requested by the user (after adapting it to use disk).
      persist(LocalRDDCheckpointData.transformStorageLevel(newLevel), allowOverride = true)
    } else {
      persist(newLevel, allowOverride = false)
    }
  }
```

So that calls a `persist` method with an extra input argument. It looks like this:

```
  /**
   * Mark this RDD for persisting using the specified level.
   *
   * @param newLevel the target storage level
   * @param allowOverride whether to override any existing level with the new one
   */
  private def persist(newLevel: StorageLevel, allowOverride: Boolean): this.type = {
    // TODO: Handle changes of StorageLevel
    if (storageLevel != StorageLevel.NONE && newLevel != storageLevel && !allowOverride) {
      throw SparkCoreErrors.cannotChangeStorageLevelError()
    }
    // If this is the first time this RDD is marked for persisting, register it
    // with the SparkContext for cleanups and accounting. Do this only once.
    if (storageLevel == StorageLevel.NONE) {
      sc.cleaner.foreach(_.registerRDDForCleanup(this))
      sc.persistRDD(this)
    }
    storageLevel = newLevel
    this
  }
```

In there, we see something interesting. If the current `storageLevel` (not the new one) == `StorageLevel.NONE`, we're going to `registerRDDForCleanup` and `persistRDD` on this RDD.

Now, the [default value](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/fbbcf9434ac070dd4ced4fb9efe32899c6db12a9/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L1825) for `storageLevel` is `StorageLevel.NONE`. That means that your case (calling `persist` on an unpersisted RDD) falls under this category.

So we found out that calling `rdd.persist(StorageLevel.NONE)` actually does something with your RDD! Let's have a look at both of these operations.

#### registerRDDForCleanup

`registerRDDForCleanup` is a [method](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/fbbcf9434ac070dd4ced4fb9efe32899c6db12a9/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ContextCleaner.scala#L151-L185) of the `ContextCleaner` class. It looks like this:

```
  /** Register an RDD for cleanup when it is garbage collected. */
  def registerRDDForCleanup(rdd: RDD[_]): Unit = {
    registerForCleanup(rdd, CleanRDD(rdd.id))
  }

  // some other code between here that I removed for this explanation

  /** Register an object for cleanup. */
  private def registerForCleanup(objectForCleanup: AnyRef, task: CleanupTask): Unit = {
    referenceBuffer.add(new CleanupTaskWeakReference(task, objectForCleanup, referenceQueue))
  }
```

So this method actually adds a cleanup task (associated with this RDD) to some buffer called the `referenceBuffer`. That looks like this:

```
  /**
   * A buffer to ensure that `CleanupTaskWeakReference`s are not garbage collected as long as they
   * have not been handled by the reference queue.
   */
  private val referenceBuffer =
    Collections.newSetFromMap[CleanupTaskWeakReference](new ConcurrentHashMap)
```

So as the code comments are saying, this `referenceBuffer` is a buffer to ensure that tasks don't get garbage collected too soon. So your RDDs are getting less garbage collected, which improves your performance!

#### persistRDD

The second method that was called on our RDD is the `persistRDD` method. I won't go into too much detail (since it is less important here) but this method (of [Sparkcontext.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/fbbcf9434ac070dd4ced4fb9efe32899c6db12a9/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala#L1915-L1920)) basically adds this RDD to a `Map` in which the SparkContext keeps track of all persisted RDDs.

#### Conclusion

We could go deeper in this investigation, but that would become impractical to write/read. I think this level of abstraction is enough to understand that calling `rdd.persist(StorageLevel)` actually does something to make your RDDs not be garbage collected too soon!

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you @Koedlt. These are interesting insights. I learned a few things. However, the answer didn't address the question. I have two setups: 1) persist and reuse -> 22x improvement. 2) Not persist, only reuse -> 4x improvement. In the 2nd case, I never call persist on the RDD (storage never changes), but why do I see improvement? Could it be due to Spark automatically caches shuffle intermediate files?

Comment: @Phaniarnab oh I misread your question then! I thought you were actually calling `rdd.persist(StorageLevel.NONE)`. So just to understand: what is the difference between your first scenario (no improvement) and your third scenario (4x improvement)?

Comment: In the first scenario, I don't reuse the RDD, instead generating a new RDD for the same operation. Say, I have a bunch of operations happening in a loop. I recognize that one shuffle-based operation among those doesn't depend on the loop variables (i.e. repetitive in each iteration). Case1: I create a new RDD for that operation for each iteration. Case2: I cache that RDD in the first iteration, call persist(), and use the same RDD from the next iteration. Case3: I cache the RDD, do not call persist(), but reuse from the next iteration.

Comment: Hmmm could you make a tiny bit of Scala/Pyspark code that illustrates what you mean? Just something like 10-20 lines of code might be enough to get to the essence of your question maybe? It's hard to really see what's going on and make a proper response without seeing any code about this.